# location-based multi-factor authentication for Windows 10 login with a local account

Tags: windows-10, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm looking to enable MFA for login to my Windows 10 laptop, which I use with a local account (no microsoft login).  However, 90% of my use is at home, where I don't want to be required to plug in a dongle or fiddle with my phone every time the laptop screen locks.

I have a Thinkpad with a fingerprint reader, and I guess I'd accept fingerprint + password as an "all locations" MFA requirement.  (Even though fingerprints are not great as a factor.)  But I've not found a way to do that with a local account.  And ideally, I'd prefer the MFA requirements to change based on whether I'm at home or elsewhere:  at home, require fingerprint or fingerprint + password;  elsewhere, require password + (dongle or phone).

Is there any third-party or microsoft native MFA solution that does this?  It should also fail gracefully to something secure if there's no internet connection, and/or if I lose my dongle, etc.  (E.g., I'm overseas, and my hardware factors are stolen or stop working.)

Comment: Might be a stupid point.. but can't you use a VM to use the MFA requirement when you need it?

Comment: You do understand that strictly speaking fingerprint authentication isn’t MFA since it replaces the password.  Likewise, a MFA solution, would require your password and the additional code that is generated.

Comment: You don't need to fiddle with your phone, it just needs to be with you to automatically unlock the computer.

Comment: Yes - I know that Win 10 doesn't seem to offer fingerprint PLUS password.  I mentioned above that I couldn't find a way to do that, at least not with a local account.  

I keep bluetooth on my phone & laptop turned off when not in use - for battery & security reasons.  So there would be fiddling necessary, unfortunately.